Error made in git repo, not sure how to resolve or if it's even possible
I had a bunch of changes that hadn't been committed yet, that's the real problem I know. I wanted to switch to a new branch and commit the changes there. To do that, normally I'll git stash then create and switch to new branch, then git stash pop on the new branch and commit and push.
However, this time I messed up bad. I didn't use the new switch command correctly. I don't know what I was thinking but I used git switch -C improvements origin/main. This wouldn't have been so bad except I think there were changes on my local main that conflicted with the changes that came from the git stash pop and there are many changes and many of them critical.
I still have the terminal open from where I did this, if anyone can help me just undo what I did I would be very grateful. I'm concerned that by doing it this way it may be impossible to recover the changes from git stash because I popped them off the stack now they're no longer retrievable. If they are somehow retrievable then I could just create a new branch and use them there.
I've tried going line by line in the code to salvage what I can and I've tried using timelines to reset files but I swear I can still see changes that I don't want in there after I do this. I would just revert or reset but because I hadn't committed before the merge I'm not sure there's anywhere to revert to?
Last login: Mon Jul 15 02:41:33 on ttys000
benarceneaux@Bens-MacBook-Pro ~ % git switch -C improvements origin/main
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
benarceneaux@Bens-MacBook-Pro ~ % cd Dev
benarceneaux@Bens-MacBook-Pro Dev % cd 4scorexxp 
benarceneaux@Bens-MacBook-Pro 4scorexxp % cd ..
benarceneaux@Bens-MacBook-Pro Dev % cd Mickeygrove 
benarceneaux@Bens-MacBook-Pro Mickeygrove % git switch -C improvements origin/main
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    Assets/Resources/Anchors/Test1.prefab
    Assets/Scenes/Creator.unity
    Assets/Src/.DS_Store
    Assets/Src/ARWorldMapController.cs
    Assets/Src/PlaceOnTap.cs
    Assets/Src/SerializableSoundTrigger.cs
    Assets/Src/SoundTrigger.cs
    Assets/Src/TrackableManager.cs
    Packages/manifest.json
    Packages/packages-lock.json
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting
benarceneaux@Bens-MacBook-Pro Mickeygrove % git add -all
error: did you mean `--all` (with two dashes)?
benarceneaux@Bens-MacBook-Pro Mickeygrove % git stash
Saved working directory and index state WIP on implement-trigger-inflation: beb419a Small changes and fixes
benarceneaux@Bens-MacBook-Pro Mickeygrove % git switch -C improvements origin/main
branch 'improvements' set up to track 'origin/main'.
Switched to a new branch 'improvements'
benarceneaux@Bens-MacBook-Pro Mickeygrove % git stash pop
Auto-merging Assets/Resources/Anchors/Test1.prefab
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Assets/Resources/Anchors/Test1.prefab
CONFLICT (modify/delete): Assets/Resources/Anchors/TriggerAnchor1.prefab deleted in Stashed changes and modified in Updated upstream.  Version Updated upstream of Assets/Resources/Anchors/TriggerAnchor1.prefab left in tree.
Auto-merging Assets/Scenes/Creator.unity
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Assets/Scenes/Creator.unity
warning: Cannot merge binary files: Assets/Src/.DS_Store (Updated upstream vs. Stashed changes)
Auto-merging Assets/Src/.DS_Store
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Assets/Src/.DS_Store
Auto-merging Assets/Src/ARWorldMapController.cs
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Assets/Src/ARWorldMapController.cs
Auto-merging Assets/Src/PlaceOnTap.cs
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Assets/Src/PlaceOnTap.cs
Auto-merging Assets/Src/SerializableSoundTrigger.cs
Auto-merging Assets/Src/SoundTrigger.cs
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Assets/Src/SoundTrigger.cs
Auto-merging Assets/Src/TrackableManager.cs
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Assets/Src/TrackableManager.cs
Auto-merging Packages/manifest.json
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Packages/manifest.json
Auto-merging Packages/packages-lock.json
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Packages/packages-lock.json
On branch improvements
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    modified:   .vscode/settings.json
    deleted:    .vsconfig
    deleted:    Assets/CameraController.cs
    deleted:    Assets/CameraController.cs.meta
    modified:   Assets/LiberationSans SDF Material Variant.mat
    deleted:    Assets/Prefabs/AnchorListItem.prefab
    deleted:    Assets/Prefabs/AnchorListItem.prefab.meta
    modified:   Assets/Prefabs/AnchorPrefab.prefab
    modified:   Assets/Prefabs/AnchorPrefab.prefab.meta
    deleted:    Assets/Prefabs/AudioSource.prefab
    deleted:    Assets/Prefabs/AudioSource.prefab.meta
    deleted:    Assets/Prefabs/Client Panel.prefab
    deleted:    Assets/Prefabs/Client Panel.prefab.meta
    deleted:    Assets/Prefabs/Host Panel.prefab
    deleted:    Assets/Prefabs/Host Panel.prefab.meta
    deleted:    Assets/Prefabs/Network Test.meta
    deleted:    Assets/Prefabs/Network Test/Player.prefab
    deleted:    Assets/Prefabs/Network Test/Player.prefab.meta
    deleted:    Assets/Prefabs/Network Test/UI.meta
    deleted:    Assets/Prefabs/Network Test/UI/Connection Request Slot.prefab
    deleted:    Assets/Prefabs/Network Test/UI/Connection Request Slot.prefab.meta
    deleted:    Assets/Prefabs/Network Test/UI/Nearby Host Slot.prefab
    deleted:    Assets/Prefabs/Network Test/UI/Nearby Host Slot.prefab.meta
    deleted:    Assets/Prefabs/Network Test/UI/Player Slot.prefab
    deleted:    Assets/Prefabs/Network Test/UI/Player Slot.prefab.meta
    deleted:    Assets/Prefabs/Rtt.prefab
    deleted:    Assets/Prefabs/Rtt.prefab.meta
    modified:   Assets/Prefabs/ScrollableListItem.prefab
    deleted:    Assets/Prefabs/SoundAnchor.prefab
    deleted:    Assets/Prefabs/SoundAnchor.prefab.meta
    deleted:    Assets/Prefabs/StartPanel.prefab
    deleted:    Assets/Prefabs/StartPanel.prefab.meta
    modified:   Assets/Resources/Anchors/Test1.prefab.meta
    deleted:    Assets/Resources/Anchors/TriggerAnchor1.prefab.meta
    deleted:    Assets/Resources/Prefabs.meta
    deleted:    Assets/Resources/Prefabs/AnchorPrefab.prefab
    deleted:    Assets/Resources/Prefabs/AnchorPrefab.prefab.meta
    modified:   Assets/Src/AnchorPanel.cs
    modified:   Assets/Src/Constants.cs
    deleted:    Assets/Src/DebugConsole.cs
    deleted:    Assets/Src/DebugConsole.cs.meta
    modified:   Assets/Src/ScrollableList.cs
    modified:   Assets/Src/ScrollableListItem.cs
    modified:   Assets/Src/SerializableSoundTrigger.cs
    modified:   Assets/Src/Settings.cs
    modified:   Assets/TextMesh Pro/Resources/Fonts & Materials/LiberationSans SDF - Drop Shadow.mat
    modified:   Assets/TextMesh Pro/Resources/Fonts & Materials/LiberationSans SDF.asset
    deleted:    Assets/WorldAnchor.cs
    deleted:    Assets/WorldAnchor.cs.meta
    deleted:    OHMYGOD DAVE!!!
    modified:   ProjectSettings/TagManager.asset

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
    both modified:   Assets/Resources/Anchors/Test1.prefab
    deleted by them: Assets/Resources/Anchors/TriggerAnchor1.prefab
    both modified:   Assets/Scenes/Creator.unity
    both modified:   Assets/Src/.DS_Store
    both modified:   Assets/Src/ARWorldMapController.cs
    both modified:   Assets/Src/PlaceOnTap.cs
    both modified:   Assets/Src/SoundTrigger.cs
    both modified:   Assets/Src/TrackableManager.cs
    both modified:   Packages/manifest.json
    both modified:   Packages/packages-lock.json

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    Assets/Prefabs/DestroyButton.prefab
    Assets/Prefabs/DestroyButton.prefab.meta
    Assets/Prefabs/SoundTriggerPrefab.prefab
    Assets/Prefabs/SoundTriggerPrefab.prefab.meta
    Assets/Resources/Anchors/Test2.prefab
    Assets/Resources/Anchors/Test2.prefab.meta
    Assets/Src/Events.cs
    Assets/Src/Events.cs.meta
    Assets/Src/Testing.meta
    Assets/Src/Testing/
    Assets/Src/WorldAnchor.cs
    Assets/Src/WorldAnchor.cs.meta
    Assets/XRI.meta
    Assets/XRI/

The stash entry is kept in case you need it again.
benarceneaux@Bens-MacBook-Pro Mickeygrove % git add --all
benarceneaux@Bens-MacBook-Pro Mickeygrove % git commit -m "Initial commit"
[improvements 26b9e19] Initial commit
 Committer: Ben Arceneaux <benarceneaux@Bens-MacBook-Pro.local>
Your name and email address were configured automatically based
on your username and hostname. Please check that they are accurate.
You can suppress this message by setting them explicitly:

    git config --global user.name "Your Name"
    git config --global user.email you@example.com

After doing this, you may fix the identity used for this commit with:

    git commit --amend --reset-author

 73 files changed, 2755 insertions(+), 13900 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 .vsconfig
 delete mode 100644 Assets/CameraController.cs
 delete mode 100644 Assets/Prefabs/AnchorListItem.prefab
 delete mode 100644 Assets/Prefabs/AudioSource.prefab
 delete mode 100644 Assets/Prefabs/Client Panel.prefab
 rename Assets/Prefabs/{Network Test/UI/Player Slot.prefab => DestroyButton.prefab} (62%)
 rename Assets/Prefabs/{AnchorListItem.prefab.meta => DestroyButton.prefab.meta} (74%)
 delete mode 100644 Assets/Prefabs/Host Panel.prefab
 delete mode 100644 Assets/Prefabs/Network Test/Player.prefab
 delete mode 100644 Assets/Prefabs/Network Test/Player.prefab.meta
 delete mode 100644 Assets/Prefabs/Network Test/UI/Connection Request Slot.prefab
 delete mode 100644 Assets/Prefabs/Network Test/UI/Connection Request Slot.prefab.meta
 delete mode 100644 Assets/Prefabs/Network Test/UI/Nearby Host Slot.prefab
 delete mode 100644 Assets/Prefabs/Network Test/UI/Nearby Host Slot.prefab.meta
 delete mode 100644 Assets/Prefabs/Network Test/UI/Player Slot.prefab.meta
 delete mode 100644 Assets/Prefabs/Rtt.prefab
 delete mode 100644 Assets/Prefabs/Rtt.prefab.meta
 delete mode 100644 Assets/Prefabs/SoundAnchor.prefab
 delete mode 100644 Assets/Prefabs/SoundAnchor.prefab.meta
 rename Assets/{Resources/Prefabs/AnchorPrefab.prefab => Prefabs/SoundTriggerPrefab.prefab} (95%)
 rename Assets/{Resources/Prefabs/AnchorPrefab.prefab.meta => Prefabs/SoundTriggerPrefab.prefab.meta} (100%)
 delete mode 100644 Assets/Prefabs/StartPanel.prefab
 delete mode 100644 Assets/Prefabs/StartPanel.prefab.meta
 create mode 100644 Assets/Resources/Anchors/Test2.prefab
 rename Assets/{Prefabs/AudioSource.prefab.meta => Resources/Anchors/Test2.prefab.meta} (74%)
 delete mode 100644 Assets/Resources/Anchors/TriggerAnchor1.prefab.meta
 delete mode 100644 Assets/Src/DebugConsole.cs
 create mode 100644 Assets/Src/Events.cs
 rename Assets/Src/{DebugConsole.cs.meta => Events.cs.meta} (83%)
 rename Assets/{Prefabs/Network Test.meta => Src/Testing.meta} (77%)
 create mode 100644 Assets/Src/Testing/InputEvent.cs
 rename Assets/{CameraController.cs.meta => Src/Testing/InputEvent.cs.meta} (83%)
 create mode 100644 Assets/Src/Testing/TestCameraController.cs
 create mode 100644 Assets/Src/Testing/TestCameraController.cs.meta
 create mode 100644 Assets/Src/Testing/TestInputHandler.cs
 create mode 100644 Assets/Src/Testing/TestInputHandler.cs.meta
 create mode 100644 Assets/Src/Testing/TestScrollableListItems.cs
 create mode 100644 Assets/Src/Testing/TestScrollableListItems.cs.meta
 rename Assets/{ => Src}/WorldAnchor.cs (100%)
 rename Assets/{ => Src}/WorldAnchor.cs.meta (100%)
 mode change 100755 => 100644 Assets/TextMesh Pro/Resources/Fonts & Materials/LiberationSans SDF - Drop Shadow.mat
 rename Assets/{Prefabs/Network Test/UI.meta => XRI.meta} (77%)
 rename Assets/{Resources/Prefabs.meta => XRI/Settings.meta} (77%)
 rename Assets/{Prefabs/Client Panel.prefab.meta => XRI/Settings/Resources.meta} (57%)
 create mode 100644 Assets/XRI/Settings/Resources/InteractionLayerSettings.asset
 rename Assets/{Prefabs/Host Panel.prefab.meta => XRI/Settings/Resources/InteractionLayerSettings.asset.meta} (52%)
 create mode 100644 Assets/XRI/Settings/Resources/XRDeviceSimulatorSettings.asset
 create mode 100644 Assets/XRI/Settings/Resources/XRDeviceSimulatorSettings.asset.meta
 create mode 100644 Assets/XRI/Settings/XRInteractionEditorSettings.asset
 create mode 100644 Assets/XRI/Settings/XRInteractionEditorSettings.asset.meta
 delete mode 100644 OHMYGOD DAVE!!!
benarceneaux@Bens-MacBook-Pro Mickeygrove % git push 
Enumerating objects: 103, done.
Counting objects: 100% (103/103), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (67/67), done.
Writing objects: 100% (67/67), 28.83 KiB | 1.80 MiB/s, done.
Total 67 (delta 39), reused 1 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (39/39), completed with 28 local objects.
To github.com:skynard/Mickeygrove.git
   4b5bca7..26b9e19  improvements -> main
benarceneaux@Bens-MacBook-Pro Mickeygrove % git status
On branch improvements
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    Assets/Resources/Anchors/TriggerAnchor1.prefab.meta

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
benarceneaux@Bens-MacBook-Pro Mickeygrove % git log
commit 26b9e19e098254f81ef8e3498f26a8493cf373a2 (HEAD -> improvements, origin/main, origin/HEAD)
Author: Ben Arceneaux <benarceneaux@Bens-MacBook-Pro.local>
Date:   Wed Jul 17 20:58:35 2024 -0600

    Initial commit


4b5bca7 (HEAD -> improvements, main) HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD~
26b9e19 (origin/main, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to HEAD
26b9e19 (origin/main, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{2}: reset: moving to 26b9e19e098254f81ef8e3498f26a8493cf373a2
e077976 HEAD@{3}: revert: Revert "Initial commit"
26b9e19 (origin/main, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{4}: reset: moving to 26b9e19e098254f81ef8e3498f26a8493cf373a2
4a4905b (origin/improvements) HEAD@{5}: commit: initial commit
26b9e19 (origin/main, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{6}: reset: moving to HEAD
26b9e19 (origin/main, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{7}: reset: moving to HEAD
26b9e19 (origin/main, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{8}: commit: Initial commit
4b5bca7 (HEAD -> improvements, main) HEAD@{9}: checkout: moving from implement-trigger-inflation to improvements
beb419a (origin/implement-trigger-inflation, implement-trigger-inflation) HEAD@{10}: reset: moving to HEAD
beb419a (origin/implement-trigger-inflation, implement-trigger-inflation) HEAD@{11}: checkout: moving from main to implement-trigger-inflation

Edit
I've managed to get to a point where I can see my changes are there, pending commit. However, there's a merge happening that I can't get rid of. I've tried git reset --merge and git reset --abort but after all the things I had deleted are still present. I'm not sure what to do...

First thing to learn: Don't stash changes; make a commit instead. They are so much easier to retrieve and to back out.

@j6t fwiw a stash is a commit, just a somewhat more temporary one.

First of all, don’t panic. By using git stash you’ve saved all of your work in a temporary commit. Because there was a conflict, the stashed commit wasn’t removed, and should still be accessible (you can check git stash list to confirm).
Even if the stash is gone, you can retrieve it from git reflog --all (look for the entry WIP on implement-trigger-inflation).
Just in case, you may wish to back up a copy of the entire working directory including the .git folder before doing anything else.
If you just want to go back to the way things were before:
# first check out the branch you were on before
git checkout implement-trigger-inflation
# then “manually” apply the stashed commit
# (get the commit ID of the stash from git reflog)
# if the stashed commit is still in the stash, you can simply `git stash pop` here
git checkout <stash commit ID> -- .


I did panic, you should see the rest of the terminal output. But what you're saying is that I can look at git stash list and find the stash with the changes I want to keep and somehow pop that onto a new branch?

Technically the stash contains a full copy of your code as it is a proper commit; it just doesn’t show up in the current branch. Therefore you can actually treat it as a regular commit - check it out, merge it with other commits (which is basically what git stash pop does), etc.

When I do a git stash list I don't see anything that would be helpful, nothing I can't see in SourceGit visually.  However, I did a git reflog and I think I can see what I'm looking for there. Specifically, that first stash I did, those are the changes I want to cherry pick. Would this be the one I want?: 4b5bca7 (HEAD -> improvements, main) HEAD@{9}: checkout: moving from implement-trigger-inflation to improvements

Ah sorry, try git reflog --all to see stash entries.

By the way, based on your output (The stash entry is kept in case you need it again.), the stash entry should still be around in git stash list, unless there's additional terminal output that you haven't shown.

I can't tell which one it is, I don't know how you can, can you?

Based on your output, the stash you made before switching should read WIP on implement-trigger-inflation: beb419a Small changes and fixes. (By the way: edit your own question, not the answer!)
